# Node.js/Express.js: does response.send() can have a callback?

Tags: node.js, express, httpresponse

My question is can i execute business logic once the res.send() had successfully ended?
I'm using Node.js and Express.js.

Something like: (The following code will not work)

```
res.send("Hello World",function(err,res){
        log(err + "  " + res); // Will execute once res.send succeed and the user received "Hello World"
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.send()` does not have a callback as it is not an asynchronous method. Also, it will never throw an error.

You can continue on writing code the method and you will be sure that the response has already been sent. Obviously, you won't be able to add anything to the `response` variable afterwards since it's already been sent to the user.

Comment: That pretty much what i though, however, is there a way to know if `send()` were successfully executed?

Comment: It cannot be executed unsuccessfully.